# Use regular expressions in R strsplit

Tags: regex, r, strsplit

I would like to split "2015-05-13T20:41:29+0000" into 2015-05 and 20:41:29+0000. I tried the following:

```
> strsplit("2015-05-13T20:41:29+0000",split="-\\d\\dT",fixed=TRUE)
[[1]]
[1] "2015-05-13T20:41:29+0000"
```

but the pattern is not matched. How to fix this?

Comment: This is the answer. Post it and I will mark it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can remove the `fixed` since you are not using exact matching,

```
strsplit("2015-05-13T20:41:29+0000",split="-\\d{2}T")
# [[1]]
# [1] "2015-05"       "20:41:29+0000"
```